# Equivalent SSIS expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ss

I am unable to convert the following SQL to a corresponding SSIS expression
and cast it to DATE format

```
 SUBSTRING(A.FILENAME,13,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(A.FILENAME,15,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(A.FILENAME,17,4)
```

This is the best I could get

```
DT_DATE(SUBSTRING(@[User::V_LoadFileName],13,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@[User::V_LoadFileName],15,2)+''+SUBSTRING(@[User::V_LoadFileName],17,4))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

String to cast to Date in SSIS has to be **YYYY-MM-DD**.
If you want to cast String to Datetime, it should be **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MIS:SS**.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning for the formatted data in Ferdipux's answer is that your environment may not be using the same style of DATE (i.e. YYYY/MM/DD vs YYYY/DD/MM).

Also, your example has syntax problems. Casting in SSIS is a little odd. You close your parenthesis BEFORE the variable.

`(DT_BOOL)"0"` returns `FALSE`

Note also the use of TWO quotations in SSIS. So you will likely need to use `'"'` in your script to work.

Some examples of casting in SSIS:

`( «type» ) «expression» 
(DT_I4)
(DT_STR, «length», «codepage» )
(DT_DATE)
(DT_BOOL)
(DT_WSTR, «length» )
(DT_NUMERIC, «precision», «scale» )
(DT_DECIMAL, «scale» )
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)`

Lastly, if you can, use the Expression Tester. Made life REALLY easy for me in designing my own SSIS packages. :D

http://expressioneditor.codeplex.com/