# Datetime convert error in SSIS

Tags: datetime, ssis, type-conversion

I want to import a huge csv-file with datetime-column in format YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm:ss.nnn (2015.09.28 00:00:02.721). It is the supported string literal format for datetime:
[datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).
I'm using DT_DBTIMESTAMP as the Integration Services data type:
[Integration Services Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036(v=sql.120).aspx).
But the import does not work due to convertion error. I can only import in format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnn. My OS, SQL 2014 and DB are all in german. How can I execute this task without search and replace in csv with regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean about Regular Expressions - but here is a solution for you:

You can import the file into a temporary holding table and then convert it to a datetime using the DataConversion task.

You can also apply the following SQL to your table - which is probably going to be quicker:

```
UPDATE tempTable SET NewDateCol = CAST(OldDateCol AS DATETIME)
```

where `OldDateCol` is the imported text field containing the "invalid" date format.

Because we know that this will work:

```
SELECT CAST('2012.05.06 11:25:33.123' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I must use regular expession with search and replace, because point is also delimiter for milliseconds and I cannot use fast replace with e.g. FART (http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/). We are speaking here about huge csv-files (above 100M rows) and I cannot believe, that I need extra conversion step with source file or SQL to achieve proper type conversion?

Comment: PS Thanl you very much for your suggestion, CAST works properly. But I search for solution without extra step, pehpaps with BULK INSERT and format file - will it work?

Comment: I don't think you need an "extra" step - when importing your input column within your flatfile connection should be set to DT_DBTIMESTAMP2.

Answer (score 0):

Pure SSIS dataflow solution - Derived Column transformation with the following formula for NewDateCol

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2)(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(OldDateCol,1,10),".","-")+SUBSTRING(OldDateCol, 11, LEN(OldDateCol)))
```

Basically, this expression replaces . with - on the first 10 symbols and then appends the rest.

Comment: Why do you need to do a replace?

Comment: @BIDeveloper, string to be casted to SSIS Datetime has to be in format YYYY-HH-MM hh:mm:ss.nnn. So, before type cast periods should be replaced with dashes.

Comment: Try this: SELECT CAST('2012.05.06 11:25:33.123' AS DATETIME)

...No **REPLACE** required.

Comment: @BIDeveloper, the point of this character replace is to completely eliminate need for temp holding table from your answer. Pure SSIS data transformation without additional SQL roundtrip.

Comment: ... yes... and as I said in my answer... you don't need one :-)

Furthermore, there is no need to do a REPLACE. Which was my original point to you.

Comment: @BIDeveloper, just tested your setup - my server has russian locale so it expects datetime as YYYY/MM/DD .... Created test file with two lines of data - like 2016.01.02 00:00:01.123, described this field as DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 in Flat File Source. Data Viewer displays an error "ttt Error: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime." So, when SSIS engine cannot parse string as DateTime in its own, you have to align it with standard format YYYY-MM-DD ....

Comment: I don't think, that it is an SQL issue, because i can execute this without error in my german database:DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '2015.09.28 00:00:01.159'; SELECT @datevar; GO  
Nevertheless I habe allready enabled and created contained databases with english and british english as default language - same error.
I have also created the user with english and british english as default language - same error.

Comment: And I have allready tested with different DB-Providers (ODBC, OLE DB und native) - without success.
I think, that it is the SSIS string parser, that cannot correctly translate such date format as YYYY.MM.DD from string literal.
Can you help me, what language has actually such date format?

Comment: @BernLiefer - SSIS default format for datetime string literal is **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnn** [my reply on similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37804038/1010622).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:
1. CREATE TABLE with datetime (it makes milliseconds rounding error - 2015.09.28 00:00:01.159 is 2015-09-28 00:00:01.160 etc., for whatever reason) or datetime2(3) (2015.09.28 00:00:01.159 is 2015-09-28 00:00:01.1590000 - correct but oversized) 
2. SET DATEFORMAT ymd
3. BULK INSERT from csv with TABLOCK and CODEPAGE='RAW' to increase perfomance